# Difference between Ziegler–Natta method and Phillips method

Tags: polymers, catalysis

I have to compare the similarities and differences between the Zieglerr–Natta method and Phillips method of producing polyethylene. However, the only difference I can find is the difference in catalyst used.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!